automatic cleanup of postgres db after each test
I have sqlalchemy application that talks with a postgres db. I want to do some "integration tests" using testcontainers and trying the various scenarios.
just to make things simple, let's say that in my application I just expect a single table users with at least the admin row.
I expect this to be available in all tests. It's like my "baseline" of db status.
I then want to do multiple tests, for example to check if I can login to the application, both for admin and/or normal users
I want to create different "scenarios" - potentially one for each test, with different data on the db.
For example, I want to do 3 tests

where there is only the admin row
where there are 2 rows: admin and user_foo
where there are 4 rows: admin, user_x, user_y, user_z

for each test I want / need to write 3 different fixtures. I may use "raw sql" or sqlalchemy itself, it's not important now.
but after the run of the test (that itself may also change the content of the db) I need to "rollback" to the original "baseline" status.
However I cannot just run ROLLBACK as all the changes have actually been committed.
How can I ensure that the db is in the "baseline" status (+ appropriate fixture) before each test?
The only solution I've found are

drop the db and rebuild it from scratch before each test
manually write the appropriate sql to restore the db status
ignore the issue and hope it works...

The first one is slow to run, the second is unmantainable and the third... is not a solution.
Ideally I would like to have a way to tell pg to "tag" the status of the db and restore it after I've run the test.
Is it possible?

Dump ypur DB before test, and restore from dump after...

If I read your question correctly, it sounds like you want to have a test database with some prepopulated test data, commit to that database, then magically rollback those commits. Luckily sqlalchemy can do that, according to the documentation Joining a Session into an External Transaction (such as for test suites).
Copied from link:
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from unittest import TestCase

# global application scope.  create Session class, engine
Session = sessionmaker()

engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://...")


class SomeTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # connect to the database
        self.connection = engine.connect()

        # begin a non-ORM transaction
        self.trans = self.connection.begin()

        # bind an individual Session to the connection, selecting
        # "create_savepoint" join_transaction_mode
        self.session = Session(
            bind=self.connection, join_transaction_mode="create_savepoint"
        )

    def test_something(self):
        # use the session in tests.

        self.session.add(Foo())
        self.session.commit()

    def test_something_with_rollbacks(self):
        self.session.add(Bar())
        self.session.flush()
        self.session.rollback()

        self.session.add(Foo())
        self.session.commit()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.session.close()

        # rollback - everything that happened with the
        # Session above (including calls to commit())
        # is rolled back.
        self.trans.rollback()

        # return connection to the Engine
        self.connection.close()

